# django custom template filter with variable as argument

Tags: python, html, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

I'm using a Django custom template filter as described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/howto/custom-template-tags/) to access entries in a 3D array in my template. I pass the 3D array swipeData from views.py to index.html.

index.html:

```
function getNearestHalfHourTimeString() {
    var now = new Date();
    var hour = now.getHours();
    var minutes = now.getMinutes();
    var ampm = "AM";
    if (minutes < 15) {
        minutes = "00";
    } else if (minutes < 45){
        minutes = "30";
    } else {
        minutes = "00";
        ++hour;
    }
    return("T" + hour + minutes);
}    

var currentDay = (new Date()).getDay();
var currentTimeRounded = getNearestHalfHourTimeString();

{% block content %}
{% load hello_extras %}
    var atrium = {{swipeData|bldIndex:'ATRIUMCAFE'|dayIndex:currentDay|timeIndex:currentTimeRounded }};
{% endblock %}
```

hello_extras.py:

```
from django import template

register = template.Library()

@register.filter
def bldIndex(List, strIndex):
    dctBuild = {'ATRIUMCAFE':0, 'BUTLERCOLLEGE':1, 'CAFEVIVIAN':2, 'CENTERFORJEWISHLIFE':3, 'CHANCELLORGREEN':4, 'CHEMISTRYCAFE':5, 'CONCESSIONS_12':6, 'FORBESCOLLEGE':7, 'FRISTCSTORE':8, 'FRISTGALLERY1':9, 'FRISTGALLERY2':10, 'FRISTGALLERY3':11, 'FRISTGALLERY4':12, 'FRISTWITHERSPOONS':13, 'GRADUATECOLLEGE':14, 'LIBRARY_CART':15, 'MATHEYCOLLEGE':16, 'ROCKEFELLERCOLLEGE':17, 'STUDIO34BUTLEREMPORIUM':18, 'WHITMANCOLLEGE':19, 'WILSONCOLLEGE':20, 'WOODROWWILSONCAFE':21, 'FIRESTONELIBRARY':22}
    i = int(dctBuild.get(strIndex))
    return List[i]

@register.filter
def dayIndex(List, strIndex):
    return List[int(strIndex)]

@register.filter
def timeIndex(List, strIndex):
    dctTime = { "T0000":0, "T0030":1, "T0100":2, "T0130":3, "T0200":4, "T0230":5, "T0300":6, "T0330":7, "T0400":8, "T0430":9, "T0500":10, "T0530":11, "T0600":12, "T0630":13, "T0700":14, "T0730":15, "T0800":16, "T0830":17, "T0900":18, "T0930":19, "T1000":20, "T1030":21, "T1100":22, "T1130":23, "T1200":24, "T1230":25, "T1300":26, "T1330":27, "T1400":28, "T1430":29, "T1500":30, "T1530":31, "T1600":32, "T1630":33, "T1700":34, "T1730":35, "T1800":36, "T1830":37, "T1900":38, "T1930":39, "T2000":40, "T2030":41, "T2100":42, "T2130":43, "T2200":44, "T2230":45, "T2300":46, "T2330":47}
    i = int(dctTime.get(strIndex))
    return List[i]
```

I get the error

```
VariableDoesNotExist at /
Failed lookup for key [currentDay] in u"[{
```

How can I use a variable as an argument to my custom template filter? I've tried using a with block already.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are trying to pass a JS var to a django filter, that it's wrong

currentDay and currentTimeRounded are JS Vars not Python vars, for this reason filter fails

Remember that you can get all necessary info in your view, and then render in your template

I suggest you that format your data in your view and in the template assign it to the respective JS var

some as follow

```
def some_view(request):
    # here you can calculate, convert, create all values to your chart as you need
    # if you need time or date can use datetime module ie

    values_to_chart = ""

    render(request, template_name, locals())
```

And in your template

```
var atrium = {{values_to_chart}}
```